# How to compress videos in Expo before uploading to Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, react-native, compression, firebase-storage, expo

I would like to know how can I compress videos from Expo/React Native/Nodejs, in order for them to be lighter before uploading them to Firebase Storage.

An example of this is Whatsapp, a phone-recorded video has a size of over 35mb, but when you select it to send it to someone else, it shows it has a size of around 5-6mb, pretty compressed and without huge quality loss.

I may be able to use an API, but I'd rather know if it's posible to do this with the current resources mentioned before (Expo, etc)

Comment: You have to use any library for this like :react-native-video-processing

Comment: @SalmanSaleem The problem is, the library will work if it's pure react native. It needs you to modify the build for android and ios, specific files that are used without Expo. When you use expo, it's pretty much one kind of file for both formats, so the file is not modifiable in that case, which will make the library not work.

Comment: did you find any answer to this question yet?

Comment: Hey @StackGU, I stopped working on this project and didn't have to use videos on Expo again, so nope :/

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback anyway!

Comment: Seems this is a dead end with Expo. Unless anyone has any other leads...

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is quite old already it's still the first result on Google when looking for something like "expo compress video" so I think it's worth adding a follow-up answer.

Since early 2022, [ffmpeg-kit-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-kit-react-native?activeTab=readme) is available for dev-client builds using a [config-plugin](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/react-native-ffmpeg)

Answer (score -8):

Use the aspect ratio 4:3 while recording the video.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera#arguments-1